# GAS : folder.addEditor() : Mail Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have create this google apps script in order to create folders (in google drive) and share them.

But sometime I got this error message when the addEditor function runs : 
**https://script.google.com says : Error encountered : E-mail incorrect : myemail@mydomain.com**

But if I directly insert this email in the sharing panel of the folder then it works...

```
*//---- EMAILS

function validateEmail (emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}

//---- FOLDERS


function FolderCreateByPathShared(path,editorsList,viewersList){   
  // path e.g. : 'F1/F2/F3', 'F1' created in root
  // e.g. : FolderCreateByPathShared('F1/F2/F3',['toto.titi@domaine.com'],[''])

  var f=FolderCreateByPath(path);

  if(viewersList){
    for(var c=0 ; c<viewersList.length ; c++){
       if(validateEmail(viewersList[c])) f.addViewer(viewersList[c]);
    }
  }

  if(editorsList){
    for(var c=0 ; c<editorsList.length ; c++){
       if(validateEmail(editorsList[c])) f.addEditor(editorsList[c]);
    }
  }  

  return f;
}*
```

Comment: When you say 'sometimes' do you mean with some email adress ( and reproducible?) or sometimes randomly and then working?

Comment: yes some email address. Always the same. I don't understand why It work if I insert the same email address directly in the sharing panel of the folder. Why google allow it in this case and not in the other...

Comment: How can I catch this error message ? My scripts are aborted by this kind of error.

Comment: Have you tried to put the addEditor in a try-catch structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It works.
I can try & catch the error. :-)

But now does someone know why some mails are blocked by these instructions ? 
When I insert the same blocked mails in the sharing panel of the folder then it works...

Comment: Have you checked the strings that are actually returned by your validateEmail function on these particular emails ?